# Copy a file that is in the middle of being written

Tags: filesystems, io

I have a program that writes to the standard output. It does not write all info at once, it does computation and then writes new bits.
The output of the program is being stored in a file.

```
$ ./theprogram.sh > results.csv
```

While the script was running I copied `results.csv` to peek at numbers.
After that, next copies of the file show no changes even though some records should be added there. What happened to the original file after I copied during writing? Are new records being discarded?

Comment: Did you modify or replace `results.csv` at all?

Comment: No, what I did is `cp results.csv results_copy.csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use,

`tail -f results.csv` to watch file whilst it grows you can break out of tail with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

`less` will work as well. Use the less command <kbd>G</kbd> to take you to the last line of the file, then <kbd>F</kbd> will follow, similar to `tail` above.

piping through tee eg. `./theprogram.sh | tee results.csv`  allows you to watch output on stdout and log to a file simultaneously.

Your copy shouldn't have affected anything. However you are running a script, could there possibly be something in that script that would expect exclusive access to the output file and abort if it doesn't get it ? Personally I doubt it.